# How to open a new tab via a button using the Ubuntu Touch Qt SDK?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I blame it on my tiredness but I'm struggling to find how to direct the user to a new tab via a button:

- I've got a Login page and if the user has placed the right username and password, pressing on the Login button will direct the user to a new tab.

  ```
  TextField {
                  id: inputTo
                  placeholderText: "Username:"

              }

              TextField {
                  id: inputFrom
                  placeholderText: "password"
                  echoMode: TextInput.Password
              }


              Button {
                  objectName: "button"
                  width: parent.width

                  text: "Login"

                  onClicked: {
                      if(inputTo.text == "----" & inputFrom.text == "---" ){
                          label.text = "Succesful"


                      } else label.text = "Wrong Username or Password"
                  }
              }
  ```

Can anybody provide me on how to allow the button to direct the user to a new tab? thankyou :)

Comment: its all good, managed to just create a pagestack and let the button to allow pagestack to push the new tabs ^_^.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the Ubuntu-SDK tab-template to enable a password check.
I am also totally new to qml but maybe this is what you want:

---

Project->new->ubuntu->Ubuntu-UI-Tabs  as tabstest:
Here is my tabstest.qml

---

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

/*
   example : check password before changing/showing tab
*/

MainView {
// objectName for functional testing purposes (autopilot-qt5)
objectName: "mainView"
applicationName: "tabstest"

width: units.gu(100)
height: units.gu(75)

Tabs {
    id: tabs
    anchors.fill: parent

    // First tab begins here
    Tab {
        objectName: "Tab1"

        title: i18n.tr("Password-Entry-tab")

        // Tab content begins here
        page: Page {
            Column {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                Label {
                    text: i18n.tr("this is the password check tab")
                }
            }
        }
        Column {
            id: pageLayout

            Label{
                id : labelX
                text : "Enter your paasword:"
            }

            TextField {
                id: inputFrom
                placeholderText: "password"
                echoMode: TextInput.Password
            }
            Button {
                objectName: "button"
                width: parent.width

                text: "Login"

                onClicked: {
                    console.debug("onclicked...");
                    if(inputFrom.text == "test" ){
                        labelX.text = "Succesful"
                        console.debug(tabs.selectedTab );
                        tabs.visible = false
                        tabs2.visible = true
                    } else {

                        labelX.text = "Wrong Username or Password"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Tabs {
    id: tabs2
    visible: false

    // Second tab begins here
    Tab {
        objectName: "Tab2"

        title: i18n.tr("..secured tab")
        page: Page {
            anchors.margins: units.gu(2)

            tools: ToolbarActions {
                Action {
                    objectName: "action"

                    iconSource: Qt.resolvedUrl("avatar.png")
                    text: i18n.tr("Tap me!")

                    onTriggered: {
                        label.text = i18n.tr("Toolbar tapped")
                    }
                }
            }

            Column {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                Label {
                    id: label
                    objectName: "label"

                    text: i18n.tr("you are in secured tab.")
                }
            }
        }
    }        anchors.fill: parent
}
}
```

---

regards
Sascha